# Add space to elements got from RSS with jQuery

Tags: jquery, rss, tumblr

I'm trying to change Tumblr posts class by getting the tags from RSS.

I already got the tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rssurl = '/tagged/ExampleTag/rss';
    $.get(rssurl, function(data) {
    $('#content').append('<div class="example_post">');
    var $xml = $(data);
    var vari = 0;
        $xml.find("item").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                item = {
                    link: $this.find("link").text(),
                    category: $this.find("category").text(),
                    description: $this.find("description").text()
            }
            vari = vari +1;
            if(vari <3){
            $('#content').append('<div class="example_post ' + item.category + '" style="overflow:hidden;"><div class="featured_description' + vari + '">' + item.description + '</div><div class="example_link"><a href="' + item.link + '">Example</a></div></div>');

            }
        });
        $('#content').append('</div>');
    });
</script>
```

The problem is when I add the class to the "example_post" class ( item.category ), if it has more than one category, there is no space between classes.

Example:

Tag is "travel" - This is what I get

```
<div class="example_post travel"> ...
```

Tags are "travel, inspiration & life" -

```
<div class="example_post travelinspirationlife"> ...
```

What I want is to get this:

```
<div class="example_post travel inspiration life"> ...
```

Sorry for the bad explication & thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over `category` tags and concatenate them with each other using spaces

```
$xml.find("item").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var categories = '';
    $this.find("category").each(function(){
      categories +=$(this).text()+" ";
    });
    item = {
        link: $this.find("link").text(),
        category: $.trim(categories),
        description: $this.find("description").text()
    }
    vari = vari +1;
    if(vari <3){
    $('#content').append('<div class="example_post ' + item.category + '" style="overflow:hidden;"><div class="featured_description' + vari + '">' + item.description + '</div><div class="example_link"><a href="' + item.link + '">Example</a></div></div>');

    }
});
```

Comment: I am Glad to help you :):)